# Find all tuples within a list of tuples

Tags: erlang, tuples, key, key-value

I'm currenty in my second semester of my master in computer science and taking a course in programming distributed systems. Therefore we're supposed to submit weekly exercises which also include coding exercises in Erlang.

As this is the second week of the course we only just started with Erlang and this is the first exercise where we're supposed to implement 6 functions within a module. The first 5 functions I could easily do by myself, however I'm completely overwhelmed by the 6th. For that one we're supposed to write a function that takes 2 inputs: a list of tuples representing key-value pairs and a list containing keys to search for. The function then is supposed to search through the entire list for all occurences of these keys and return them.

As this first exercise on Erlang is meant for us to get familiar with the basic concepts of the language which means that we're supposed to solve these tasks rather by using recursion instead of something like lists:max.

I was able to implement a working function for a previous task that simply searched in a list of key-value pair tuples for one key and returned the first result. The implementation of that one seemed quite easy but for the extension of this task I tried so many things that didn't work that I don't even know what to try next.

Currently I experimented with this approach:

```
find_all(Keys, Values) ->
  AllFindings = [],
  lists:foreach(
    fun(Key) ->
      lists:foreach(
        fun(Value) ->
          {X, Y} = Value,
          case X == Key of
            true -> AllFindings:append(Value);
            false -> []
          end
        end,
        Values
      )
    end,
    Keys
  ),
  AllFindings.
```

The problem with this is that either I need to do something like appending the values to the initially created list (which gives me this error: `Warning: invalid module and/or function name; this call will always fail` and also I'm not sure if that is even possible in the way that I intend it to work because it would require the variable AllFindings to change its value) or that I need a way to save the values for later use so I can output them all together at a later point in time when I have all values together.

But I'm not really sure how to properly achieve that.

The previous ways I tried to implement this were something like this, using recursion but didn't work the way I intended them to work (some of the value outputs in this version where only for "debugging" to see what variable has which value at what state of the function):

```
find_all(Keys = [KeyHead | KeyTail], Values = [ValueHead | ValueTail]) ->
  Tuples = [X || X = {KeyHead, Y} <- [ValueHead]],
  Tuples,
  ValueTail,
  case Tuples /= [] of
    true -> Tuples
  end,
  case ValueTail /= [] of
    true -> find_all(Keys, ValueTail);
    false ->
      case KeyTail /= [] of
        true -> find_all(KeyTail, Values);
        false -> find_all(KeyTail, ValueTail)
      end
  end.
```

And:

```
find_all([], []) -> [];
find_all([KeyHead | KeyTail], [ValueHead | ValueTail]) ->
  case ValueHead of
    {KeyHead, V} -> V;
    {_, V} -> find_all(KeyTail, ValueHead);
    _ -> find_all(KeyHead, ValueTail)
  end.
```

I'd be really grateful for any advice on solving this, either by suggesting some code or by pointing me towards the corresponding literature because for me the literature/forums on Erlang seem pretty sparse and harder to find (especially when compared to popular languages like Java or Python). So far I'm also reading "Learn You Some Erlang" but didn't come across any particular part where I thought that it might help solving this problem.

**EDIT**

I now came up with this piece of code:

```
find_all(Keys, Values) ->
  while(Keys, Values).

while([], []) -> [];
while(Keys = [KeyHead | KeyTail], Values = [ValueHead | ValueTail]) ->
  NumberOfKeys = length(Keys),
  LengthOfValues = length(Values),
  {K, V} = ValueHead,
  erlang:display(Keys), erlang:display(Values),
  case NumberOfKeys > 1 of
    true -> case LengthOfValues > 1 of
              true -> case K =:= KeyHead of
                        true -> [ValueHead | find_all(Keys, ValueTail)];
                        false -> [find_all(Keys, ValueTail)]
                      end;
              false -> case K =:= KeyHead of
                         true -> [ValueHead];
                         false -> []
                       end
            end;
    false -> case LengthOfValues > 1 of
               true -> case K =:= KeyHead of
                         true -> [ValueHead | find_all(Keys, ValueTail)];
                         false -> [find_all(Keys, ValueTail)]
                       end;
               false -> case K =:= KeyHead of
                          true -> [ValueHead];
                          false -> []
                        end
             end
  end,
  while(KeyTail, Values).
```

It looks quite promising in my opinion as a smaller version of it already returns {d, 3} for this function-call `warmup:find_all([d, x, c], [{c, 5}, {z, 7}, {d, 3}, {a, 1}]).`. When debugging with `erlang:display()` for different values I could see that it's looping over the first key 4 times and also reduces the `ValueTail` to the last value, then moves on to the next key. However I'm confused why then `Values` still contains only the last value `{a, 1}`, as I thought that the recursion goes back to the top-level of its calls where the list still should contain all values?

Comment: Please just describe (with examples) what should be input and what should be output and why you can not make output from input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is long, so for clarity, here's the problem statement: write a function that takes a list of key-value pair tuples and a list of keys, and, using recursion, returns a list of each pair whose key matches any of the given keys. Given this problem statement, we can write the top of our module — let's call it `keyfinder` — to export a `find/2` function:

```
-module(keyfinder).
-export([find/2]).
```

Now, let's consider the trivial cases:

1. *Empty list of pairs:* return an empty list.
2. *Empty list of keys:* return an empty list.

We can write these two cases using pattern matching:

```
find([], _) -> []; % no pairs
find(_, []) -> []; % no keys
```

Next, let's consider the remaining case where we have pairs and keys: given *n* keys, we have to search the pairs list *n* times and keep a list of every match we find. To track matches, we can use an accumulator list, starting as empty. Perhaps we can use a `find/3` for this, where the extra argument is the accumulator:

```
find(Pairs, Keys) ->
    find(Pairs, Keys, []).
```

We want `find/3` to call itself recursively to find all matches, so let's consider the cases `find/3` has to deal with:

1. *The key of the head of the pairs list matches the key at the head of the keys list:* add the pair to the accumulator and recursively search the rest of the pairs for the same key.
2. *The key of the head of the pairs list does not match the key at the head of the keys list:* recursively search the rest of the pairs for the same key.
3. *The keys list is empty:* return the accumulator.
4. *The pairs list is empty:* our recursion eventually arrives here by walking through the pairs list; recursively search the whole pairs list for each of the remaining keys.

In the last case above, our recursion could lead to a case where we've examined all pairs, thus emptying our pairs list, but there are still more keys to search; this means we need to keep the original list of pairs around somewhere to restart our search with the next key. One way to do this is to add another argument, which is the original list of pairs:

```
find(Pairs, Keys) ->
    find(Pairs, Keys, Pairs, []).
```

This makes our recursive function `find/4` instead of `find/3`, and we pass that original list of pairs along, unchanged, to every `find/4` call.

Let's make `find/4` handle each of the four cases described above:

```
%% We exhausted the list of keys, so return the results.
find(_, [], _, Results) -> Results;

%% We exhausted the list of pairs, so search for the rest of the keys.
find([], [_|Keys], OriginalPairs, Results) ->
    find(OriginalPairs, Keys, OriginalPairs, Results);

%% Our pair matches our key, so add the pair to the accumulator and continue the search.
find([{Key,_}=Pair|Pairs], [Key|_]=Keys, OriginalPairs, Results) ->
    find(Pairs, Keys, OriginalPairs, [Pair|Results]);

%% No match, continue the search.
find([_|Pairs], Keys, OriginalPairs, Results) ->
    find(Pairs, Keys, OriginalPairs, Results).
```

The most interesting case is the third clause where we use pattern matching in the function head to match the key in the pair with the key at the head of the keys list. When that match occurs, our recursive call to `find/4` passes a new accumulator consisting of the newly-found pair as the head of the new accumulator and the original accumulator as its tail. Both that function clause and the last one use the tail of the list of pairs as the first argument to the recursive `find/4` invocation.

The full module:

```
-module(keyfinder).
-export([find/2]).

find([], _) -> [];
find(_, []) -> [];
find(Pairs, Keys) ->
    find(Pairs, Keys, Pairs, []).

find(_, [], _, Results) -> Results;
find([], [_|Keys], OriginalPairs, Results) ->
    find(OriginalPairs, Keys, OriginalPairs, Results);
find([{Key,_}=Pair|Pairs], [Key|_]=Keys, OriginalPairs, Results) ->
    find(Pairs, Keys, OriginalPairs, [Pair|Results]);
find([_|Pairs], Keys, OriginalPairs, Results) ->
    find(Pairs, Keys, OriginalPairs, Results).
```

Let's compile it and try it in the Erlang shell:

```
1> c(keyfinder).
c(keyfinder).
{ok,keyfinder}
2> keyfinder:find([],[]).
keyfinder:find([],[]).
[]
3> keyfinder:find([{a,1}],[]).
keyfinder:find([{a,1}],[]).
[]
4> keyfinder:find([],[a]).
keyfinder:find([],[a]).
[]
5> keyfinder:find([{a,1}],[a]).
keyfinder:find([{a,1}],[a]).
[{a,1}]
6> keyfinder:find([{a,1},{a,2}],[a]).
keyfinder:find([{a,1},{a,2}],[a]).
[{a,2},{a,1}]
7> keyfinder:find([{a,1},{a,2}],[a,b]).
keyfinder:find([{a,1},{a,2}],[a,b]).
[{a,2},{a,1}]
8> keyfinder:find([{a,1},{b,2}],[a,b]).
keyfinder:find([{a,1},{b,2}],[a,b]).
[{b,2},{a,1}]
9> keyfinder:find([{a,1},{b,2},{c,3}],[a,b]).
keyfinder:find([{a,1},{b,2},{c,3}],[a,b]).
[{b,2},{a,1}]
10> keyfinder:find([{a,1},{b,2},{c,3}],[a,b,c,d,e]).
keyfinder:find([{a,1},{b,2},{c,3}],[a,b,c,d,e]).
[{c,3},{b,2},{a,1}]
```

Seems to work as expected.

Notice that the results list is ordered from the last match found to the first, which is caused by the fact that we prepend each result to the accumulator list. If you prefer the reverse order, and if you're allowed to use the `lists` module, you can change the first clause of `find/4` to reverse the result before returning it:

```
find(_, [], _, Results) -> lists:reverse(Results);
```

If you're not allowed to use the `lists` module, then you can prevent the need for reversing the result by instead appending each pair to the accumulator list:

```
find([{Key,_}=Pair|Pairs], [Key|_]=Keys, OriginalPairs, Results) ->
    find(Pairs, Keys, OriginalPairs, Results++[Pair]);
```

Note that this is a bit less efficient than prepending, though.

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed and in-depth answer, probably the most detailed I've ever seen on SO. This solution is flawless and I could follow each step of your explanation easily and think it definitely helped me in understanding the structure of erlang a bit better. Thank you so much for dedicating so much of your time (which writing this answer more than likely has taken) to helping me!

Answer (score 0):

You can try use lists generators for find tuples in the lists.

- Find tuples with key/value in simple lists:

```erlang
1> [X || {_, _} = X <- [{a, 1}, 1, [2], {b, 2}, {c, 3}, 4]].
[{a,1},{b,2},{c,3}]
```

- Find tuples in nested lists:

```erlang
1> Data = [[d, x, c], [{c, 5}, {z, 7}, {d, 3}, {a, 1}, 1, [1, 2, {x, 1}, {j, 1}]]].
[[d,x,c],[{c,5},{z,7},{d,3},{a,1},1,[1,2,{x,1},{j,1}]]]
2> [X || {_, _} = X <- lists:flatten(Data)].
[{c,5},{z,7},{d,3},{a,1},{x,1},{j,1}]
```

- Find tuples without tying the number of elements of tuple in nested lists:

```erlang
1> Data = [[d, x, c], [{c, 5, 5}, {z, 7}, {d, 3, 3}, {a, 1}, 1, [1, 2, {x, 1, 1}, {j, 1}]]].
[[d,x,c],
 [{c,5,5},{z,7},{d,3,3},{a,1},1,[1,2,{x,1,1},{j,1}]]]
2> [X || X <- lists:flatten(Data), is_tuple(X)].
[{c,5,5},{z,7},{d,3,3},{a,1},{x,1,1},{j,1}]
```